# Get data from multiple tables in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have  tables

- Networks

| nid | nname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | network 1 |
| 2 | network 2 |
| 3 | network 3 |

- Shows

| sid | sname | s_nid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | show 1 | 1 |
| 2 | show 2 | 1 |
| 3 | show 3 | 2 |

- Episode

| eid | ename | e_sid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | episode 1 | 1 |
| 2 | episode 2 | 1 |
| 3 | episode 1 | 2 |

- Episode_ratings

| erid | ervalue | er_eid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

How do I get all the shows with nid 1 , whilst also getting the episodes of each show and the ratings of each episode?

Is this simply not possible without running many queries?

Comment: Find an SQL manual and look up JOIN. Give something a try, come back if you have a code related problem

Answer (score 1):

You just need a single query for this using JOIN. Kindly read up references on how to use JOIN like this one for example [JOIN Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) . The relationship between the tables are already in place. You can try this query to get all of the columns from each table. Just modify the * with the specific columns that you would need.

```
SELECT *
FROM Networks 
    INNER JOIN Shows
        ON Networks.nid = Shows.s_nid
    INNER JOIN Episode 
        ON Shows.sid = Episode.e_sid
    INNER JOIN Episode_ratings 
        ON Episode.eid = Episode_ratings.er_eid
WHERE Networks.nid = 1
```